# Can you make maven build until you get a successful build?

Tags: java, maven

Sometimes, I want to be away from keyboard for a while and before I go away I start my maven build, hoping that I can come back to see that the build has been successful.

But sometimes I come back and it says "build failed" then I build my project again and get "build successful", there are various reasons for this, maybe your antivirus was running and blocking access to a certain folder at the time of build or something like that.

Is it possible to make maven retry build command until you get "build successful"?

Comment: You can probably setup a bash script to do this.  But have a look at tools like Jenkins, which are designed for such continuous build integration.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks! I thought maven could do this by itself.

Comment: I don't think it can.  Do you really need this?  I mean, how long do your builds take?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen about 10 minutes.

Comment: First you need to understand why the failures occur..just saying sometimes it fails and yes in particular on Windows antivirus software can cause such things, but this a problem on your machine site not on Maven site...

Comment: @khmarbaise my company demands that I use an antivirus, I can't even control it.

Comment: Yes of course but there are areas on the hard drive where it does not make sense..in particular in the workspace where you are working with your IDE and where artifacts are being created like the `target` directories etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own script to launch the command for the build process but there are some considerations to do before doing it:

1. Does it makes sense to expect that a failed build may succed without a code modification?
2. How frequent the retry should be? If it is too much than you can potentially cause problems on the machine that you are running the script.

If you expect that 1) is possible than for 2) you can implement a non linear pollicy; for instance you can use exponential retry; similar to the policy done in Spring for the annotation `@Retryable`.